# Spawn command as sudo in NPM/Yeoman

Tags: linux, apache, npm, yeoman, sudo

I'm learning Yeoman and have gotten really far which is nice :), but I'm now at the point in my generator where I would like to set up a VHOST for my new project.

The way I normally create a VHOST is create a *.conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, run `sudo a2ensite new-site` and finally `sudo service apache2 reload`.

How can I use `generator.spawnCommand()` (or anything else that works) to run my sudo commands? I assume the user would need to enter his password for the commands to run of course.

Note that I've tried the sudo npm package but it just fails silently even with the example code provided on https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo

Comment: My guess is that Yeoman swallows the output, that's why you never see the password prompt. You can try setting up your account in /etc/sudoers as described here, this enables "passwordless" sudo: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo

Comment: @TudorIlisoi thanks, but since I'm not the only one who will be using this generator, I'd prefer it if the user didn't have to do anything particular before using it. I'm considering just leaving the user a message at the end stating exactly which commands to run to finish the installation.

Comment: Well, maybe you can try `spawnCommandSync` instead of `spawnCommand` and add some event handlers to check the result  https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/545

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood something, but the following simple code worked fine for me:

```javascript
var generators = require('yeoman-generator');
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  touch: function () {
    execSync('sudo touch /tmp/test-sudo', {
      stdio: 'inherit'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Trying this I get the same as when I do `generator.spawnCommand()`: "powerbuoy is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
Error: Command failed: sudo touch test". Even if this can be solved by adding me to the "sudoers file" (whatever that is :P) I'd prefer it if user's wouldn't need to do anything special before  running the generator.

Comment: @powerbuoy, but using `sudo` implies using the `sudoers` file. Unless the user is satisfied with the defaults, he (or his administrator) has to modify the file. If the user is not allowed to run sudo, then I  see no other way around but to edit the `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Ok, but if I manually run `sudo touch test.txt` I get asked for my password and then the file is created. When I run it from my generator I get the message above and nothing happens. I'd like the former to happen without me having to edit files. Perhaps it's not doable but then I'd rather just leave a message at the end telling the user what command to run (I'm doing this now in fact).

Comment: @powerbuoy, strange, if in both cases it was the same user. The generator above asks for password when I run `yo mysudo`.

Comment: @powerbuoy, maybe your code overrides something through environment variables(`man sudo`). I would test the above mentioned code in a minimal project.

Comment: Perhaps, but if my code somehow changed the user I wouldn't expect the message to be "**powerbuoy** is not in the sudoers file" (powerbuoy is my username, and like I said running sudo as powerbuoy outside of the generator works fine...). I did also comment all my other code before trying your example. The only thing left was the requires at the top of the file. But I do appreciate your help :) And tbh the way I have it now is "fine". I just leave the user with a command he needs to run manually.